# Getting javascript error in the in-built file of moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N72vy.png)

From past 2 weeks we are having JavaScript error for in-built library files of the Moodle.

All the popups is not working properly on the site and giving following error:

I have tried looking for the solution but didn't find anything . and this issue related to library file of Moodle 3.8.2+

Comment: hmm perhaps try upgrading the bundle?

Comment: Post the (relevant) code where the error ocurrs, and the full (non-screenshot) error.

Comment: Can you explain the steps to reproduce the error - is this a forum in a course?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'oop')
    at x (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:9:2083)
    at YUI._use (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:9:2830)
    at YUI.use (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:9:943)
    at Object.getLegacyEvents (ajax.js:45:189)
    at Object.setUp (ajax.js:255:568)
    at ?redirect=0:2141:12
    at Object.execCb (require.min.js:1:12861)
    at b.check (require.min.js:1:6615)
    at b.enable (require.min.js:1:9363)
    at b.init (require.min.js:1:5721)

Comment: this error is all over the place in the website and restricting many functionalities. We haven't changed anything at the code level